# Page is not displaying JSON object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My code is not playing object properties into the console, however the code displays the object just fine. What am I not able to access the information in this object?

Here is my code:

```
//                 APOD
(function Apod() {
    var api_key = 'NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo';
    var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod' + "?api_key=" + api_key;
    var apodRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var apodDATA = "";
    apodRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        apodRequest.onload = function() {
            var responseObject = apodRequest.response;
            apodDATA = responseObject;
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $("#apodimage").attr("src", responseObject.hdurl);
            });
            console.log(responseObject.url);
        };
}
    apodRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    apodRequest.send(null);
}());
```

Here is the JSON "object" that displays fine on the responseObject variable (properties are giving me undefined):

```
{
  "date": "2016-11-06",
  "explanation": "A mere 20,000 light-years from the Sun lies NGC 3603, a resident of the nearby Carina spiral arm of our Milky Way Galaxy. NGC 3603 is well known to astronomers as one of the Milky Way's largest star-forming regions. The central open star cluster contains thousands of stars more massive than our Sun, stars that likely formed only one or two million years ago in a single burst of star formation. In fact, nearby NGC 3603 is thought to contain a convenient example of the massive star clusters that populate much more distant starburst galaxies. Surrounding the cluster are natal clouds of glowing interstellar gas and obscuring dust, sculpted by energetic stellar radiation and winds. Recorded by the Hubble Space Telescope, the image spans about 17 light-years.   Follow APOD on: Facebook,  Google Plus,  Instagram, or Twitter",
  "hdurl": "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1611/ngc3603_hubble_3885.jpg",
  "media_type": "image",
  "service_version": "v1",
  "title": "Starburst Cluster in NGC 3603",
  "url": "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1611/ngc3603_hubble_960.jpg"
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `$.ajax` ?

Comment: are you getting those values in console?

Comment: I have not learned how to use $.ajax yet as I am still a month and a half into javascript, I am learning about json and jquery at the moment.

And no I am not getting any values in console. But when I do console.log(responseObject) it displays that object code above

Comment: Please check the value of `apodRequest.responseType`. Is it "json"?

Comment: It turned out it was a string and that was the reason. Ty

Comment: Terminology: [there's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2):

What you get from the server is probably just a string, not an object.

You can parse the JSON string and convert it to object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var obj = JSON.parse(responseObject);
console.log(obj.url);
```

You can check the type of the variable using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). So if you print `console.log(typeof responseObject)`, you'll get `"string"`. If it was an object, you'd get `"object"`.

Also, since you are already using jQuery, consider doing ajax requests by jQuery itself. It would be way more elegant. Read the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Yeah this fixed it for me. Thank you

Comment: *"You can parse the string and convert it to JSON"* - No, the string *is* JSON, which you parse to get an *object*. JSON is a text format.  Your code is correct, but your terminology is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

USE `JSON.parse` for converting your response to `json` because your request is returning `string`
**Note:-** Do not use `$("document").ready()` inside ajax response

its working fine for me

```
(function Apod() {
    var api_key = 'NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo';
    var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod' + "?api_key=" + api_key;
    var apodRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var apodDATA = "";
    apodRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        apodRequest.onload = function() {
            var responseObject = apodRequest.response;
            apodDATA = responseObject;
            $("#apodimage").attr("src", responseObject.hdurl);
         var json =  JSON.parse(responseObject);
            console.log(json.url);
        };
}
    apodRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    apodRequest.send(null);
}());
```

Comment: Yeah this fixed it for me. Thank you

Comment: glad to help @Chris.. Please also don't use document.ready inside response